# No Action Method Defined, this error is in response of a curl request using codeigniter 4

Tags: php, methods, response, php-curl, codeigniter-4

```
$curlRes = \Common::curlRequests($url, $headers, 'post', array('post_data' => $field_string, 'curl_timeout' => 60));
```

This I am doing to make curl request as a method of POST, but I am getting ***No Action Method Defined*** as response. Cannot find the solution. Tried searching using error: No Action Method Defined as keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying many times finding solution, came to know that method should be **POST** instead of **post**. Unable to find solution using the keyword ***No Action Method Defined***.